# How to filter out expected error in robot framework report?

Tags: robotframework

I 'd like to filter out from the robot framework report all the expected errors. 
Typically, in [Teardown] I often delete some stuffs that were already deleted when the test passes (but not when the test fails) to guarantee a clean situation for next tests. I 'm using "Run Keyword And Ignore Error" then the test passes but in the report, section "Test Execution Errors", all the errors are logged.
Is there a way to not log these expected errors?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide example? Documentation of "Run Keyword And Ignore Error" keywords say that "Runs the given keyword with the given arguments and ignores possible error. ". Maybe you are using "Run Keyword And Continue On Failure"?

Comment: Yes you 're right,  "Run Keyword And Ignore Error" runs the keyword and ignore error. It works well. The test passes even if an error occurs during the keyword execution. The "issue" is in the robot report, all the error are logged even if they are expected.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. My report does not contain any errors. Could share example?